# How to simulate a click in another application’s menu?

Tags: swift, macos

For instance, what is the pure Swift equivalent of the following AppleScript:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Finder"
    click menu item "New Finder Window" of menu 1 of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1
end tell
```

Comment: You can Apple scripts from within your app. Look into the `NSAppleScript` class.

Comment: That’s what I’m currently doing, as a pis aller. But I’m looking for a pure Swift solution.